# Can Google PDF Viewer hide the lefthand navigation on a PDF by default?

Tags: google-drive, pdf, google-drive-file-viewer

Some clients of ours want to embed the following PDF in their website: https://docs.google.com/a/upshift.co.nz/file/d/0B39VaSipB41-ODk3WFRfSWRSV0k/preview

Unfortunately the viewer shows a left-hand navigation by default - which makes the presentation too wide for the website.

Is there a way of removing the left-hand navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following solution in [this forum thread](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/pk1KvDTNgd4/f15_SpWoJj4J) (all props to Yajeng). Fist get the document ID in the URL:

```
https://docs.google.com/file/d/<DOCUMENT-ID>/edit
```

Then use it like:

```
https://docs.google.com/viewer?srcid=<DOCUMENT-ID>&pid=explorer&efh=false&a=v&chrome=false&embedded=true
```

Or like:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?srcid=<DOCUMENT-ID>&pid=explorer&efh=false&a=v&chrome=false&embedded=true" width="640px" height="480px"></iframe>
```

Comment: Cool :) Check [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23021605/1287812) that I wrote after this one, it got a couple of more tips.

Comment: Google Docs viewer (`https://docs.google.com/viewer?...`) was retired. See the reference on my [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/101753/88163) to another question.

Answer (score 0):

At this time the viewer doesn't show a left-hand navigation as you can see on the following screenshot taken after following the link in the question.

[image]